# Dynamic SOQL with bind variable when variable equal to null

Tags: soql, null, bind-variable

I saw some strange from my point of view behavior for SOQL in apex when tried to compare with variable that is null, like:

```
Date notInitializedBirthdate;
List<Contact> cnts = [
    SELECT Id, Birthdate
    FROM Contact
    WHERE Birthdate != NULL AND Birthdate > :notInitializedBirthdate
    LIMIT 10
];
System.debug(cnts);
```

I expect that if notInitializedBirthdate is null then SOQL will not return any records, but seems that this clause `Birthdate > :notInitializedBirthdate` fully ignored.

Is it expected behavior? I not found on the apex developer guide any information about such cases.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: it's the expected behavior, but there is no documentation page about it.

I guess you expected no records since the documentation about `>`, `>=`, `<` and `<=` [operators](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_expressions_operators_understanding.htm) states

> If `x` or `y` equal null and are Integers, Doubles, Dates, or Datetimes, the expression is false.

It could be tested with the following snippet:

```java
Datetime nullDate;
Datetime now = System.now();
System.debug(now > nullDate);
System.debug(now < nullDate);
Assert.isFalse(now > nullDate);
Assert.isFalse(now < nullDate);
```

Anyway if you try this query `SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE Birthdate > null`, you'll get an error stating "invalid operator".
Most likely, instead of throwing a runtime error when a binded variable resolves to null, the query engine removes/ignores that clause. Indeed the following queries will return the same records:

```java
Datetime nullDate;
[SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE CreatedDate > :nullDate]
[SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE CreatedDate < :nullDate]
[SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE NOT(CreatedDate > :nullDate)]
[SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE NOT(CreatedDate < :nullDate)]
```

Comment: yes I expected to have false also in SOQL - but also I think that throwing error is more appropriate in given case than just ignore and return all records in case of null in variable - this will cause potentially issue in business logic. Best to just have exception than process data in invalid manner

Comment: @AliaksandrLuferau I agree that a coherent behavior would be the best. I also think that even submitting a case to SF support, they won't provide insight about the reason behind this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

This is classic behavior, well expected but never explained, as far as I know. I've found this useful for a number of use cases, such as making otherwise dynamic queries into inline queries for compiler safety (i.e. I can't mess up a query and get away with it until runtime), particularly when writing Apex REST services.

If you want exceptions, use `Database.queryWithBinds`. This method accepts a query string, a map of strings to objects for binding, and an `AccessLevel` parameter to control user or system access mode. This method will throw an exception if any keys are null or not defined in the map, or if the values for any of those keys are null. The only downside is that you have a string, so you lose some compile-time safety in exchange for this extra power.

Comment: make sense. Thank you for explanation! When I know about this behavior then it is easy to deal with. Only good to know that this is expected (if it was documented - will be great) feature and not some undefined behavior that can be changed on the future.